# `npm Err! code1` when installing puppeteer

Tags: javascript, npm, next.js, puppeteer

I'm getting the following error message when trying to install puppeteer.

OS: Linux Ubuntu 23.04
node version: v18.18.0
npm version: 10.1.0
NextJS version: v13.5.3

```
npm install puppeteer
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /path/to/project/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node install.mjs

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/usr/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T02_19_07_301Z-debug-0.log
```

got the following response as well
`{"code":"ResourceNotFound","message":"/@puppeteer/browsers/-/browse does not exist"}`

The following is the error codes saved in the debug log

```
762 verbose stack Error: command failed
762 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/lib/index.js:53:27)
762 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
762 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
762 verbose stack     at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:450:11)
762 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:517:28)
762 verbose stack     at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:350:12)
763 verbose pkgid puppeteer@21.3.5
764 verbose cwd /path/to/project/
765 verbose Linux 6.2.0-33-generic
766 verbose node v18.18.0
767 verbose npm  v10.1.0
768 error code 1
769 error path /path/to/project/node_modules/puppeteer
770 error command failed
771 error command sh -c node install.mjs
772 verbose exit 1
773 timing npm Completed in 52961ms
774 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1695781147472
775 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1695781156762
776 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1695781156763
777 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1695781156763
778 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall 1695781156769
779 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:postinstall:node_modules/puppeteer 1695781156769
780 verbose code 1
781 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/usr/.npm/_logs/2023-09-27T02_19_07_301Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried deleting the node_modules folder, deleting the package.lock.json file, clearing the NPM cache and reinstalling all the packages with the following:
`rm -rf node_modules`,
`rm -f package-lock.json`,
`npm cache clean --force`,
`npm install`